# Angular validation works on edit forms but not on new forms``

Tags: angularjs, validation

The code below illustrates angular js validation for an Edit Employee form and a New Employee form. The edit form validation works fine, the new form does not. Please help.

I checked all the tags, made sure Required is set. The newUser fields are set correctly and it will create a user if all fields are filled in.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    New Employee
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <form role="form" novalidate angular-validator name="addUserForm" angular-validator-submit="Register()">
        <table class="headerLayout">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 3px;">First Name:</td>
                <td style="padding-bottom: 3px;">
                    <input type="text" name="inputFirstName" class="form-control" ng-model="newUser.FirstName"
                           placeholder="FirstName" validate-on="blur" required required-message="'First Name is required'">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer clearfix">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="cancelCreate()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="createUser()">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
(function (app) {
'use strict';

app.controller('userNewCtrl', userNewCtrl);

userNewCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'apiService', 'notificationService'];

function userNewCtrl($scope, $modalInstance, apiService, notificationService) {

    $scope.cancelCreate = cancelCreate;
    $scope.createUser = createUser;

    function createUser() {
        $scope.newUser.Roles = $scope.selectedRoles;
        apiService.post('/api/users/add/', $scope.newUser,
            createUserCompleted,
            createUserFailed);
    }

    function createUserCompleted(response) {
        notificationService.displaySuccess($scope.newUser.UserName + ' has been created');
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
    }

    function createUserFailed(response) {
        notificationService.displayError(response.data);
    }

    function cancelCreate() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
    }
}
```

})(angular.module('mySite'));

Comment: Are there any errors in console? Can you narrow down the form to one field (create a minimal example) and add the JS code in question as well?

Comment: Sure thing, just did. Thank you for looking at it.

Comment: I do not have a $scope.newUser. I tried defining a blank one and even one with { FirstName: '' } for initialization.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was simply move the submit button within the form element.